# d3.js bubble chart animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, d3.js, circle-pack

I am working on a bubble chart application. At the moment though - my chart appears broken, not sure why.

I will be looking to try and animate the bubbles when new data sets come in.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/175/

```
setup: function(rawData, w, h){ 

            var format = d3.format(",d"),
            color = d3.scale.category20c();

            var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                .sort(null)
                .size([w, h])
                .padding(1.5);

            var svg = d3.select(methods.el).append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("class", "bubblechart")
                .attr('viewBox', "0 0 "+parseInt(w, 10)+" "+parseInt(h, 10))
                .attr('perserveAspectRatio', "xMinYMid");

            var root = methods.conformData(rawData);

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
              .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

            node.append("title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

            node.append("circle")
              .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); });
            node.append("text")
              .attr("dy", ".3em")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });

            // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
            function classes(root) {
              var classes = [];
              function recurse(name, node) {
                if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
                else classes.push({packageName: node.name, className: node.name, value: node.size});

              recurse(null, root);
              return {children: classes};
            }

                        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", h + "px"); 

            //this.resizeBubble();
        }
```

Comment: After changing to `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")` I got the complain that `rawdata` was not defined...then changed to `"children": rawData`...now some of the data is showing. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/). It is a start...

Comment: Thanks man. I've updated the fiddle to make it work again - but I am still not sure how to update the bubble chart - I've added some commented out code for transitions, but I'm not sure it adapts well to the situation. http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/2/

Comment: On the two occasions I could peek at the code, I was left with the impression that it may need a considerable re-write to get things right. Is this a mishmash of different examples? How did you put this together?

Comment: Its a mishmash of a bubble chart example - static - and a plugin.

Comment: Maybe this is a good animation example http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/

Comment: Yes, that is a constructive thought and [HERE](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2013/12/19/force-bubble-charts-in-d3) is the place to go to learn about the chart representation you mentioned. It is an outstanding tutorial.

Comment: I've added some force elements into this mock . http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/3/

Comment: I've started to place it into a plugin -so I can begin to feed it new data - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/5/

Comment: I have it updating - but the chart appears to keep gravitating towards the right hand side - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/6/ - also would like to append the labels onto the bubbles themselves

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49146/discussion-between-fernoftheandes-and-the-old-county)

Comment: I can't gain access to the chat where I am mate

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/10/ - I've updated the example with labels too - although its not perfect

Comment: I have an idea...since you cannot access the chat, why don't you post your progress as an answer and keep updating it? This way you will have everything together in one place and we get out of this long comment thread which is discouraged by SO.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the latest bubble chart code. Although its not updating correctly for multiple charts

http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/18/

```
animateBubbles: function(selector, data){
data = this.funnelData(data, methods.width, methods.height);

                                var padding = 4;
                                var maxRadius = d3.max(data, function (d) { return parseInt(d.radius)});


                                var year_centers = {
                                  "2008": {name:"2008", x: 150, y: 300},
                                  "2009": {name:"2009", x: 550, y: 300},
                                  "2010": {name:"2010", x: 900, y: 300}
                                }

                                var all_center = { "all": {name:"All Grants", x: methods.width/2, y: methods.height/2}};


                        var bubbleholder = d3.select(selector + " .bubbleholder");


                        var bubbles = d3.select(selector + " .bubbles");

                        var labelbubble = d3.select(selector + " .labelbubble");



                                var nodes = bubbles.selectAll("circle")
                                  .data(data);


                                // Enter
                                nodes.enter()
                                    .append("circle")
                                     .attr("class", "node")
                                      .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                                      .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                                      .attr("r", 1)
                                      .style("fill", function (d) { return methods.fill(d.label); })
                                      .call(methods.force.drag);

                                // Update
                                nodes
                                    .transition()
                                    .delay(300)
                                    .duration(1000)
                                      .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })

                                // Exit
                                nodes.exit()
                                    .transition()
                                    .duration(250)
                                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                                    .attr("r", 1)
                                    .remove();

                                var labels = labelbubble.selectAll("text")
                                  .data(data);              


                                // Enter
                                labels.enter()
                                    .append("text")
                                     .attr("class", "title")
                                        .text(function(d) { return d.label; })                               
                                        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
                                        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })

                                // Update
                                labels
                                    .transition()
                                    .delay(300)
                                    .duration(1000)
                               // .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
                                //.attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; })

                                // Exit
                                labels.exit()
                                    .transition()
                                    .duration(250)
                                    .remove();    


                                draw('all');


                                function draw (varname) {
                                    var foci = varname === "all" ? all_center: year_centers;
                                  methods.force.on("tick", tick(foci, varname, .55));
                                  methods.force.start();
                                }

                                function tick (foci, varname, k) {
                                  return function (e) {
                                    data.forEach(function(o, i) {
                                      var f = foci[o[varname]];
                                      o.y += (f.y - o.y) * k * e.alpha;
                                      o.x += (f.x - o.x) * k * e.alpha;
                                    });
                                    nodes
                                      .each(collide(.1))
                                      .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                                      .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });

                                      labels
                                      .each(collide(.1))
                                      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x; })
                                      .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; });

                                  }
                                }




                                function collide(alpha) {
                                  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
                                  return function(d) {
                                    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
                                        nx1 = d.x - r,
                                        nx2 = d.x + r,
                                        ny1 = d.y - r,
                                        ny2 = d.y + r;
                                    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                                      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                                        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                                            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                                            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                                            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
                                        if (l < r) {
                                          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                                          d.x -= x *= l;
                                          d.y -= y *= l;
                                          quad.point.x += x;
                                          quad.point.y += y;
                                        }
                                      }
                                      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
                                    });
                                  };
                                }                           

                    },
```

Comment: This is coming along nicely.

Comment: I'm trying to get the bubbles to adjust in size - accordingly to their svg width/height. Is there a way of forming a kind of ratio with the width/height of the chart. Also is there a way to improve the animation/tweening http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/28/

Comment: Well, off the bat, let me tell you that your efforts are quite exciting and coming at a rapid pace. I hope others with more experience and time are following them. Back to your first question, I am wondering if it could be achieved by setting up a `d3.scale` where the `domain` is the svg width/height and the `range` is the size of the bubbles (perhaps it would be two separate scales for x, width, and y, height). I am taking the liberty to ping @AmeliaBR...she may have further insights.

Comment: I've added a scale variable - not sure on the d3.scale function you spoke of. Could you modify the example to depict this? http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/33/